# pm2 deploy master latest

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, pm2

I have to be missing something. I have a basic ecosystem.json layout, with maybe the one other post deploy procedure for webpack to build the production set.

**I get no errors** on `pm2 deploy ecosystem.json staging`, yet I never get the current ref. The only time I get the latest is when I wipe the directories out and `pm2 deploy ecosystem.json staging setup`.

I've tried `pm2 deploy ecosystem.json staging update` with no luck.
Deployment is stuck at the original deploy commit. I confirm this with `pm2 deploy ecosystem.json current`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you refer this doc http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/?

Comment: right...did my post give you a sense i hadn't? To be clear I have successfully  deployed to a staging instance, the problem is that I can't re-deploy to a current commit from the master branch. The master branch is up-to date with my dev env (PM2 will tell you straight out if you hadn't pushed).